# How to call code in app.js from mithril

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mithril.js

I am creating a website where the backend is node.js with express, and clientside is using mithril. We cannot use ajax, form and jquery.

My question is how can we communicate from mithril js file to express? Let me give you example:

```
app.post("/testFunction",function(req,res){
    //Pass result
});
```

In mithril:

```
m.render(document.body, [
    m('input[type=text]'),
    m('button'),
    m('span', 'show the result')
]);
```

Here I have an input box and a button. When i click on button it should call my function in express, save data and return the message to be displayed in a `span`.

Any ideas?

Comment: You say you cannot use ajax and form, then how can you post to the server?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `m.request` to make a post to your endpoint. Check out the docs here (http://mithril.js.org/request.html). Here's a quick example.

```
m.render(document.body, [
    m('input[type=text]#testInput'),
    m('button', {
        onclick: function() {
            document.getElementById("testInput").value
            m.request({
                    method: "PUT",
                    url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/testFunction",
                    data: {
                        inputValue: document.getElementById("testInput").value
                    }
                })
                .then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                })
        }
    }, "Send Request")
]);
```